# How to make Div height: 50%? it does not work on React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Ok, so I am trying to make a todolist by using React javascript library.

**Problem**

I am trying to divide the divide the website screen by 2 div. which, one is on the top by 50% and the other is on the bottom by 50%. However,

```
.top{
  width: 50%;
  float: top;
}

.bottom{
  width: 50%;
  float: bottom;
}
```

> seems not working..

**I have tried**

Adding `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Adding `.App {text-align: center;margin:0;height:100%;}`

> and it does not give any change.

**Example**

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Navigation from './components/ToDoNav';

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation/>
        <div className="top">
            <h1>Copy</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
            <h1>Design</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> App.js

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.top{
  height: 50%;
  float: top;
}

.bottom{
  height: 50%;
  float: bottom;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

> App.css

**Result**

[image]

Comment: try this `body { margin: 0 auto; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add height 100vh to the wrapper tag (.App)

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```